# ap-angular-fullcalendar and Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular-cli

I just updated to 1.6.x of ap-angular-fullcalendar and v 6 or angular and angular-cli.  now when I run tests I am getting an error Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise' along with JQueryEventObject and JQueryAjasSettings.  I saw past issues about installing jquery typings but the library does that and I have also done it.  still throwing the error though.  Can anybody tell me how to use the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I did a poor job of reading documentation.  add this in your module fixes it:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this npm install --save-dev @types/jquery@3.2.7 and it will start working.